# Having issues installing an R package from Github

Tags: r, github, devtools

Please be patient with me as I'm a total noob, but I'm really trying to learn.

I'm trying to make a **choropleth** map for my country, and found an R package on Github that handles it excellently. However, I'm working on a university computer and I don't have write privileges on any drive but M://, so whenever the package tries to install on C:// it obviously throws an error. This hasn't been a problem since I can just specify a libpath as an argument on install.packages, but devtools::install_github does not seem to have such an argument.

I tried using

```
with_libpaths(new = "M:\R\win-library\3.2", install_github('diegovalle/mxmaps'))
```

But I got an error message saying

> with_libpaths' is deprecated. Use 'withr::with_libpaths' instead.

I take this to mean that I need to install the "withr" package in order to use that? However, I keep getting errors when trying to install that package. First, I got

> Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘withr’ had
>   non-zero exit status

because of the not having access to C:// issue. I usually bypass this by installing directly from the binaries, but when I try that it tells me

> "Warning in install.packages : package ‘withr’ is not available (for R
>   version 3.2.2)".

Other than updating my version of R (which will be a nighmare since I don't have installation privileges on this machine), how else can I either install withr or find another way to specify the directory to install the package from github?

Comment: Did you get a small window asking if it could use your personal document folder instead of the default folder? If  you just click Yes, it'd install in the documents folder where you have access.

Comment: you could try `install_github("diegovalle/mxmaps", lib="M:\R\win-library\3.2")`.

Comment: @amrrs No, I didn't get any such window. If it helps, I'm using RStudio.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I did try that, but got an error message since install_github doesn't seem to recognize the lib argument and tried to install to C:// anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with latest version of 3.4.All above mentioned packages are available under latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to set local library paths (at least on Linux running R 3.5.3):

(1) At the beginning of your script, set the the .libPaths option to your local library path, i.e.: `.libPaths("M:\R\win-library\3.2")`

(2) Add to your .Renviron file a line that specifies your local library path: i.e.:  `R_LIBS="M:\R\win-library\3.2"`

**Note:** For (1) You will need to manually run every time you start a new R session, whereas (2) will be set automatically when R starts.

Comment: Update. I found this during a bit more testing: During installation of new packages, the R_LIBS variable must be the same as what you've set .libPaths as, because R seems to look to the R_LIBS path when installing dependencies, which then will not be found when the target package is loaded if R_LIBS was different than what you set .libPaths to be. I believe this may be a bug (and makes calling .libPaths prior to installing a package useless if you are also using R_LIBS - just use R_LIBS. I didn't test whether calling .libPaths and not using R_LIBS is okay during installation).